# Searching for Junk Characters in a String

Tags: c++

Friends

I want to integrate the following code into the main application code. The junk characters that come populated with the o/p string dumps the application 
The following code snipette doesnt work..

```
void stringCheck(char*);

int main()
{
    char some_str[] = "Common Application FE LBS Serverr is down";
    stringCheck(some_str);
}


void stringCheck(char * newString)
{
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(newString);i++)
    {
        if ((int)newString[i] >128)
        {

TRACE(" JUNK Characters in  Application Error message FROM DCE IS = "<<(char)newString[i]<<"++++++"<<(int)newString[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please show me the better approaches to find junk characters in a string..

Many Thanks

Comment: The next time you're asking for help, please take the time to format your question properly. Code has to be indented by four spaces to be recognized as code. Don't use tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `char` probably is represented signed. Cast it to `unsigned char` instead to avoid that it becomes a negative integer when casting to `int`:

```
if ((unsigned char)newString[i] >128)
```

Depending on your needs, `isprint` might do a better job, checking for a printable character, including space:

```
if (!isprint((unsigned char)newString[i])) 
    ...
```

Note that you have to cast to `unsigned char`: input for `isprint` requires values between `0` and `UCHAR_MAX` as character values.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<strlen(newString);i++)
        {
                if (!iscntrl(newString[i]) && !isprint(newString[i]))
                 cout << " Invalid character entered\nTry Again!";
        }
Doesnt work

Comment: like i said, cast to unsigned char first. the behavior is undefined if you don't. existing implementations use the value to index in an array. if you don't cast, they will index into some arbitrary location. chances are that it causes some weird things to happen